# Problem with finding unused constructor parameters

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

When using Kotlin and Android Studio, Inspect code doesn't show unused constructor parameters if they are mentioned in Kotlin Docs.

[image with explanations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3bUF.png)

Is there a way to make it work?
Or is there a way to quickly delete all Kotlin Docs in the project, for manual deletion of the found parameters in a separate branch?